# How can I get connection port number in python?

Tags: python, flask, nat

I'm trying to make a NAT punchthrough for my game.

The player will connect to the Master Server (that is a python file running a flask webserver). I just need to get the player port number.

Is there someway to get the client port number in flask?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.
I just needed to use:

```
request.environ.get('REMOTE_PORT')
```